# Join query to count rows with codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

I want to count how many entries of `game_slopes` are in `game_created_slopes` with a specific value for `id_sector`.
Basically I want to know how many slopes have been created for sector 1.

`game_slopes` is the table of generic items and `game_created_slopes` is the table of the actual items created by the members.

I tried to make a select query but not sure how to go for the count.

```
$this->db->select('game_slopes.id_slope, game_slopes.id_sector, game_created_slopes.id_slope, game_created_slopes.id_player');
$this->db->from('game_slopes, game_created_slopes');
$this->db->join('game_created_slopes as created_slopes_tbl', 'game_slopes.id_slope = created_slopes_tbl.id_slope');
$query = $this->db->get();


CREATE TABLE `game_slopes` (
  `id_slope` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_sector` int(11) NOT NULL,
  ....more stuff here....
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `game_created_slopes` (
  `id_created_slopes` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_player` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_slope` int(11) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

If there is a better approach I'm up for it!

Comment: $query->num_rows() ; http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html#result-helper-methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can archive this in three ways

1. In SQL way (Using [`Count` Function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp))
2. In Codeigniter way (using [`num_rows()` Function](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html#result-helper-methods))
3. In PHP way (using [`count` Function](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_count.asp))

---

**In SQL way**

```
$this->db->select('COUNT(game_slopes.id_slope) as totalGames , game_slopes.id_slope, game_slopes.id_sector, game_created_slopes.id_slope, game_created_slopes.id_player');
```

**In Codeigniter way**

After `$query = $this->db->get();` add this `$totalGames = $query->num_rows();`

```
$query = $this->db->get();
$totalGames = $query->num_rows();
```

**In PHP way**

```
$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result_array();
$count = count($result);
if (empty($count)) {
    return false;
} else {
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I actually didn't think of the Codeigniter way, I guess I was focused into the SQL method. Is any of the method more recommended than another?

Comment: @remyremy There is no recommended. i use all of this. Which you like pick it.